# What is happening in the second Ant Man post credits scene?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, ant-man, ant-man-2015

At the end of *Ant Man*, we are treated to two excellent post credits scenes that are setting up the future of the Marvel Cinematic Universe.

One of these scenes shows us that ;

> Steve Rogers (Captain America) and Sam Wilson (The Falcon) have found Bucky Barnes (The Winter Soldier) who they have been searching for since the end of *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*. They begin to talk in hushed tones about what to do next, one of them mentioning that they "can't go to Stark. If only this had happened a week ago" (I didn't catch all the dialogue exactly, so this may be incorrect).

Obviously, this is set up for the upcoming *Captain America: Civil War* movie, but;

> Why can't they go to Stark, and what happened a week ago? Where are they, and how did they find Bucky?

In general, the things seen in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (with the exception of *Agent Carter* and *Captain America: The First Avenger*) happen in real time, so I would expect this question (or at least parts of this question) to be answerable based on what we have seen so far.

Comment: If anyone can suggest a better, non-spoiler title, that would be great.

Comment: I don't think it will surprise anyone to learn that Ant-Man, like every previous MCU film, has post-credit scenes.  It's expected at this point.

Comment: @WadCheber I meant more so that anyone else asking the question can search for it easier, not that it's a spoiler that there is a post credits scene.

Comment: I think they said they couldn't go to Stark "after what happened with the somebodies"; can't remember the exact name, but I didn't recognise it when I heard it. It's probably intended to lead up to the next Captain America, which covers the Civil War storyline, and we'll probably have to wait until then unless it's covered in a tie-in comic.

Comment: Part of me leaned towards closing under the future works policy, but we *do* have at least some bit of clues that we can start piecing together. More and more info is coming out as well.

Comment: I'm VTRO.   The answer by phantom42 is a valid answer to the question.   I think the idea that it's a scene with photography in middle of Civil War is a valid non-opinion based answer.    Everyone is too quick with the VTCs.

Comment: @ThePopMachine per [this meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5187/5184), we use "primarily opinion based" for questions about future works.

Answer (score 11):

**Answer unclear. Ask again later.**

Kevin Feige [has said](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/How-Ant-Man-Post-Credits-Scene-Connects-Captain-America-Civil-War-72641.html) that the post-credits scene (technically the only one, as the other one is a mid-credits scene) was footage shot for *Civil War* and that the scene will appear as part of the larger final cut of *Civil War* in some way (the final cut still has to be edited).

> I won’t tell you exactly where it is, but that’s photography from Civil War. **That is a part of the movie - it’s dailies from a part of the movie.** Whether it will look exactly like that in the movie I think will shift a little bit, in terms of how we cut it, but that was footage shot for Civil War.

He reiterated this in [another interview](http://zap2it.com/2015/07/ant-man-post-credits-scene-captain-america-civil-war-not-prequel-explained/)

> this one actually jumps partway into “Civil War.” Marvel Studios head Kevin Feige confirms to Zap2it that the Falcon/Captain America scene actually takes place in the middle of that movie. **“That is photography from that film that will play a part at a certain point in that film,”** he explains vaguely.

In the comics, *Civil War* is kicked off by an explosion at an elementary school involving super-powered humans. Thus far, signs point to the event being a result of events like Sokovia, Wakanda, New York, and possibly another city being destroyed.

*The Winter Soldier* ended with Cap and Falcon on a personal mission to find Bucky. Where he has been found, and why is arm is stuck is left unexplained, and what exactly the "accords" are that are mentioned, is still unclear. A number of news sources (such as [/film](http://www.slashfilm.com/second-ant-man-credits-scene/)) are reporting that the "accords" refer to "The Sokovia Accords" put in place after the events of *Age of Ultron*, but I've yet to see any official statement from anyone involved with the movie.

Whatever happened "a week ago", is likely an event that takes place during *Civil War*.

---

The actual dialog in the scene is something very close to this (this is from memory but I paid close attention the second time I saw it -- @mike):

> Falcon: This would have been much easier if it had happened a week ago.
>
> Captain: We can't call Stark...
>
> Falcon: ...because he wouldn't believe us.
>
> Captain: And even if he did...
>
> Falcon: the Accords might not let him help.
>
> Captain: We're on our own here.
>
> Falcon: Maybe not... I know a guy.

Comment: When Fiege says "That is photography from that film that will play a part at a certain point in that film", does that mean that we are actually seeing an excerpt from a scene in *Captain America: Civil War*? Also, you seem to either have a transcript of the after credits scene in question, or at least a better memory - is there any chance you could add the dialogue from the scene into your answer?

Comment: @DrRDizzle yes, that's what he's saying; that scene is either a scene from *Civil War* or at least filmed with the same props/setting/costumes/etc as something from *Civil War*.

I added my best recollection of the dialogue.

Comment: @DrRDizzle yes, we're seeing early footage shot *for* civil war let me find the other quote i read that's a bit more specific.

Comment: @DrRDizzle i updated the answer with another quote from feige.

Comment: Was it explained *why* they replaced the now traditional post-credit scene by a scene from a future movie? Introducing the Civil War will take a lot of time, an additional scene is not superfluous.

Comment: @Taladris no, but if I were to hazard a guess, i'd say that it may be because they often don't have new footage ready to go in time.

Comment: @Taladris In fairness, if I remeber correctly, the post-credit scene for *Captain America: The First Avenger* was an excerpt from the punching bag scene between Nick Fury and Steve Rogers near the start of *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble*, so this isn't the first time a post credit scene has been a sneak peak rather than a teaser.

Answer (score 3):

In the movie *Captain America: Civil War*, Iron Man/ Tony Stark wants to

> turn Bucky Barnes / The Winter Soldier in to Colonel Ross since Barnes is blamed/wanted for a bombing in Vienna. However, Captain America / Steve Rogers suspects Bucky is innocent and wants to exonerate him.

"A week ago" there were no

> formal Sokovia Accords legally limiting the freedom and choices of the Avengers. Also there was no rift between Captain America and Iron Man.

They also found

> Bucky through an inside connection via Agent Carter's niece and Shield agent Sharon Carter.

You asked where they were. I do not know where they were in that scene.