# Who did Captain America and Falcon find?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015

In the second bonus scene at the end of the credits after Ant Man,

> Captain America and the Falcon are shown with a guy they have arrested.  One of them says "This would have been a lot easier a week ago."  Then the other says "Maybe we can talk to Tony about this.". Then the first of them says something like "Who knows if the chord will allow them to help.".

**What are they talking about? And who is the guy they caught?**

I realize that some of this may not have been revealed yet, but I imagine that some of it might fit into MCU bacground stuff.

Comment: FWIW, this (unfortunately closed) question answers this: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/95991/108

Comment: yeah, this is a bit of an odd case. This question is *in no way* a duplicate of the other one, but the other question *is the answer* to this one :\

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Yep - the question that this is marked as a supliacte of (my question, incidentally) includes the information that this one is asking for already. I voted to close on the basis of the fact that this information is already available on the site, even if it is in the form of a question rather than an answer. It does raise an interesting question about how the site should handle this kind of question.

Comment: It's a dupe. This asks "who is stuck in the vice?" and "what are they talking about?" My existing answer states that they found Bucky in the vice, and that whatever they're talking about regarding the accords and tony are still unclear, but offers up the information that we have.

Comment: @phantom42 except the *answer* to that other question doesn't *answer* this one, it just talks about where the scene was from and what we do and don't know about what it means.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it might be because the answer is obvious to anyone watching the MCU movies. The person in question was the main antagonist of Captain America 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's

> Bucky Barnes, The Winter Soldier.

It's been revealed that this is a scene shot for the upcoming *Captain America: Civil War* movie, taking place some time in the early stages of that movie. As far as we know, prior to the start of *Civil War*,

> Bucky is "in hiding",

and the two Avengers have apparently found him trapped somewhere.

They're debating what to do because, assuming the Civil War plot-line in the MCU follows the comics, the Avengers aren't all on friendly terms with each other. The reference you heard is to "The Accords", which I don't recognize from the comics but is likely related to the Superhero Registration Act. They are what is preventing them from getting the help they need, and thus, they're considering calling in Scott Lang.

Comment: also... it's hard to tell from the short scene, but he hasn't been arrested. He's "stuck" in some kind of machine, and my first impression was that he got himself into that situation and was found that way.

Comment: They need an electric engineer. The obvious choice is Tony, but he is unavailable for reasons that will be made clear in the next movie. One interpretation is that his cybernetics need repairing or modifying, not that he is specifically trapped there.

Answer (score 3):

They found

> Bucky Barnes (The Winter Soldier).

Probably the new legislation requiring all super-powered beings to be registered / full disclosure is what makes it harder this week versus the last week.

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that various sources have said that *Captain America: Civil War* will almost certainly not be about a Superhuman Registration Act, as it is in the comics, thanks to the lack of superheroes with secret identities in the MCU. My answer [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/97037/24087) contains information (and some speculation) about what it is more likely to be about.

Answer (score 1):

they found

> Bucky.

From what I saw, his left arm(the metal one) appeared to be caught in some kind of vise, as if maybe he'd tried to remove it.

Comment: "I think [what Bucky was caught in was] more of a vise. But it would never happen at his own hand, by his own doing." from [/Film](http://www.slashfilm.com/second-ant-man-credits-scene/).  You should probably edit your answer to correct that detail at the end.

Comment: Well, I had the detail about maybe he'd tried to remove it because I thought that perhaps Bucky percieved it as being a physical manifestation of the Winter Soldier and that he thought that by removing it he could get rid of the Winter Soldier